# How to replace http://locallhost with ~/ in html string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, regex

I want to replace every `"http://localhost:59455/"` before `"Images/TestFiles/(file name)"` form my C# code below.

```
string tags = @"<p><img class='img - fluid' src='http://localhost:59455/Images/TestFiles/1.JPG'></p><p><br></p><p><img class='img-fluid' src='http://localhost:59455/Images/TestFiles/2.JPG'></p>";
string final = Regex.Replace(tags, "http.*/Images", "~/Images");
```

But it always give me wrong result like below:

```html
<p><img class='img - fluid' src='~/Images/TestFiles/2.JPG'></p>
```

While I expected the result like:

```html
<p><img class='img - fluid' src='~/Images/TestFiles/1.JPG'></p><p><br></p><p><img class='img-fluid' src='~/Images/TestFiles/2.JPG'></p>
```

You can see, it did replace only one.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` is **greedy** and matches everything from the first `http` to the last `/Images`. Add a `?` to make it **lazy**:

```regex
http.*?/Images
```

[More information on greedy and lazy quantifiers on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions)

[This Regex on Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=http.*%3f%2fImages&i=%3cp%3e%3cimg+class%3d%27img+-+fluid%27+src%3d%27http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a59455%2fImages%2fTestFiles%2f1.JPG%27%3e%3c%2fp%3e%3cp%3e%3cbr%3e%3c%2fp%3e%3cp%3e%3cimg+class%3d%27img-fluid%27+src%3d%27http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a59455%2fImages%2fTestFiles%2f2.JPG%27%3e%3c%2fp%3e&r=%7e%2fImages)

Be careful though, your regex will also match other paths that have `/Images` in them, like these for example:

```
http://localhost:59455/Whatever/Images
http://localhost:59455/ImagesButDifferent
```

So you might want to make it more restrictive.